# Table columns jumping when trying to resize them

Tags: css, vue.js, html-table, resize

My table always has width of 100%, but I do not know how many columns it is going to have. I need to make those columns resizable. When I do it with css `resize` property, it works, but I has some strange behaviour. When you try to resize some column, it jumps and it's like some imaginary margin is being added to `th div` you are currently resizing between resize selector and border, which I do not know how to prevent. [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1b2mdtgn/1/)

I have found some suggestions on how to fix this. If I add `1px` width to every `th` element but last one, where I set `width: auto` it works as expected. But with this implementation table starts as very narrow, and I would like it to start as if I am not using `word-break` or `white-space` properties and leave it to user to resize it the way he wants later (that is why I need those two properties, if user wants to make it narrow, he should be able to do that). [Fiddle with this fix](https://jsfiddle.net/1b2mdtgn)

So, my question is regarding the first fiddle - I need my table to has width of 100%, but how can I prevent `<thead>` of adding that margin when you try to resize?